# Java - Adding basic statistics to my program

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have created a small scanner program that removes the vowels of an inputted phrase. It's working great, except now I need to add a line displaying some simple statistics, but I don't know where to begin.

**What I have currently:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Disemvoweler();
}

public Disemvoweler() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the disemvoweling utility!\n");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your phrase: ");
    String input = in.nextLine(); // Take in the input.
    in.close(); // Close the scanner.

    System.out.println("\nYour disemvoweled phrase: "+input.replaceAll("[aeoiu]", ""));
```

**Output:**

Welcome to the disemvoweling utility!

Enter your phrase: 
Thank you for your help!

Your disemvoweled phrase: Thnk y fr yr hlp!

**What I'm trying to add to the output:**

Reduced from x to x characters.  Reduction rate of xx%

Comment: Okay, what have you attempted so far to achieve this?

Comment: It is a very simple question: just compare length of input and resulting string.

Answer (score 1):

Somebody sometimes should answer such question :) Don't forget to say hello from me to your teacher :)

```
String reduced = input.replaceAll("[aeoiu]", "");
System.out.println("\nYour disemvoweled phrase: "+reduced);
System.out.println("Reduced from " + input.length() + " to " + reduced.length() +" characters. Reduction rate of " + ((double) reduced.length()/input.length() * 100)+"%");
```

Answer (score 0):

1) `Count the number of vowels`, then

2) `calculate the percentage difference` between the `original` and the `modified` strings ...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Disemvoweler {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Disemvoweler();
}

public Disemvoweler() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the disemvoweling utility!\n");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your phrase: ");
    String input = in.nextLine(); // Take in the input.
    int inputLength = input.length();
    in.close(); // Close the scanner.
    int count = 0;
                int vowels = 0;
                int consonants = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
                {
                        char ch = input.charAt(i);
                        if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || 
                                        ch == 'o' || ch == 'u')
                        {
                                vowels++;
                        }
                }
                    System.out.println("\nYour disemvoweled phrase: "+input.replaceAll("[aeoiu]", ""));
                    String disemvoweled = input.replaceAll("[aeoiu]", "");
                    int disemvoweledLength = disemvoweled.length();
                    double percent = Math.abs(100*((double)disemvoweledLength-(double)inputLength)/(double)inputLength);
                    System.out.println("Reduced from: " + inputLength + " to " + disemvoweledLength + " characters. Reduction rate of " + percent + "%");
        }
}
```

INPUT :

```
asda alsdkaslkd asdasda aldasdjadqweeq asdoiqowie
```

OUTPUT :

```
Your disemvoweled phrase: sd lsdkslkd sdsd ldsdjdqwq sdqw
Reduced from: 49 to 31 characters. Reduction rate of 36.734693877551024%
```